# Power BI On-Premise Report Server - How to increase Report Session Time out

Tags: powerbi, session-timeout, power-bi-report-server

I have a power bi report hosted on Power BI Report server (on-premise).

The report's session time-out happens quickly.

How do I increase session time-out value of Power BI reports hosed on Power BI Report Server (On-premise) ?

Is there a way to make Report session live indefinitely ?

Regards,

Gagan

Answer (score 0):

can you try this one
Its get from Microsoft power bi community
[image]

here is the link
[link](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Service/New-Gateway-setup-timeout/td-p/642127)